# Jenkins DSL add secret file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I would like to add secret file to my job, but I can't find which keyword from Jenkis DSL it is, any suggestions?

[image]

In xml it looks like this:

```
<project>
...
<properties>...</properties>
<scm class="hudson.scm.NullSCM"/>
<builders>...</builders>
<buildWrappers>
  <org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.impl.SecretBuildWrapper plugin="credentials-binding@1.10">
     <bindings>
        <org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.impl.FileBinding>
            <credentialsId>my-keytab</credentialsId>
            <variable>KEYTAB</variable>
        </org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.impl.FileBinding>
     </bindings>
    </org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.impl.SecretBuildWrapper>
</buildWrappers>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `file` within the `credentialsBinding` context.

```
job('example') {
  wrappers {
    credentialsBinding {
      file('KEYTAB', 'my-keytab')
    }
  }
}
```

See the [API Viewer](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/job-wrappers-credentialsBinding-file) for details.